# Why the name "umbilic"?

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, math-history

Umbilic points are points on a surface at which the principle curvatures of the surface are equal. "Umbilic(al)" refers to the navel/belly button.  But why do we call these points so?  What about the surface is reminiscent of a belly button at these points?  I can only think of a swollen tummy, which might be round around the belly button, much as some surfaces are locally spherical around an umbilic point.

Comment: Maybe the author just happened to have a child and he was happy.

Comment: I would like to think so!  That would be a fun story.

Answer (score 1):

At those points,
the surface resembles
either an "innie" or an "outie".

Answer (score 1):

Another meaning of "umbilical" is "extremely close; inseparable." If you think of a surface as embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, at umbilic points, the surface is intimately attached to a bounding sphere.

Comment: Much like a bounding womb!

Answer (score 1):

The word "ombilic" is used already in [Gaston Darboux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaston_Darboux)'s text from the 19th century. See [this link](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cache/a/b/v/abv4153.0001.001/00000401.tif.20.pdf#page=8;zoom=75).

*Umbilic point* is an entry in 1700 in Joseph Moxon’s dictionary of mathematics: "Umbilique Points, or the 2 Focus or Centre-Points in an Elipsis." (see http://jeff560.tripod.com/f.html).